# Validate string value against known list of values

Tags: c#, validation

I need to build a validation function, call it, say, 'isValid'

The known valid string values are like:

```
"01"
"06"
"15"
"22"
"40"
"DA"
"F2"
```

The input is a string of unknown content.

the function prototype, contained by a static class, which hold the valid known values, is:

```
 public static bool isValid(string val);
```

What is the most efficient algorithm to do this?

I could use a

```
List<string> ValidKnownValues
```

and just see if ValidKnownValues.Contains(val)

I could use a switch statement on val, returning false on Default case

I could just compare string values

Is there a best practices approach to this simple small problem?

Comment: You should go with the most readable solution and only try to look at making it faster if you Profile and find this to be a bottle neck.

Comment: Have you tried any of the approaches you listed and timed them?

Comment: The answer is: measure yourself. Not to be rude but really, see [Which is Faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: if you have a significantly large amount of valid values, you should use a Hashset.  If not, it'll be so fast you won't notice any difference between any Collection

Comment: Have you collected evidence that this is actually a bottleneck in your overall application?

Comment: Having only 7 values and checking a string once in a while, it should never get a bottleneck and you should not be concerned, however, if it is thousands of different valid values and values are checked a lot of times, then you should look at the HashSet<string> for better performance.

Comment: It's a combination of style & performance here. I'm starting to build a large interface and want a standard for many of these things that I need to build. It needs to be as efficient as possible as it will be called in real-time by many parent systems

Comment: I wasn't asking about speed or bottlenecks. I was asking about best practice. The 'efficient' wording was a red herring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use use a `HashSet<string>` rather than a `List<string>` as this has a O(1) contains method so is very quick to look up valid known values.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: While that's true for the algorithmic complexity, it says nothing about the constants involved. If there really are only 7 values, a list look up may well be faster.

Comment: @JonSkeet - yes re-reading the question and seeing "simple small problem" at the end would maybe have me reconsider!

Comment: My concern for asking this is that it will be used as a design in many small pieces to a larger interface called by many parent systems. I don't want to regret this 6 months down the road when hundreds of such static classes are in use

Comment: Ok, I see some of my lists of values include over 130 items, so I will use a hash set

Answer (score 0):

You can also concatenate the list of possible values into a string and then search for the index of the value you are searching for:

bool test = ("01;06;15;22;40;DA;F2").IndexOf("06") > -1